# Avoid vertical scrollbar shift in container

Tags: javascript, html, css

In html, I have a panel with a fixed height which contains cards. It can contain one card or many cards. Hence, because the panel has a fixed height, it can be needed to have a scrollbar displayed in order to visualize all cards. This works properly with the property `overflow: auto`.

However, when the scrollbar is displayed, cards are shift. I would like to avoid that or at least hide this shift with a trick. I checked a lot of similar questions that suggests to use `padding-left: calc(100vw - 100%);` but it did not work since it is not the body scrollbar. **The width of the card needs to be responsive according to the container's width.**

Something that could work is to set the `overflow: overlay` and add a `padding-right`. However, this is not a standard and not compatible with firefox.

Here, you can find a reproduce example:

```js
let flag = true;

const setHeight = () => {
  if (flag) {
    document.getElementById('container').style.setProperty('height', '100%');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('container').style.removeProperty('height');
  }
  flag = !flag;
};

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', setHeight);
setHeight();
```

```css
.panel-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 510px;
  padding: 8px 20px 0;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: auto;
}

.card {
  height: 86px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  width: 14px;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 4px solid green;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">With/Without overflow</button>
<div id="container" class="panel-container scrollbar">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-left-container"></div>
    <div class="card-middle-container"></div>
    <div class="card-right-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-left-container"></div>
    <div class="card-middle-container"></div>
    <div class="card-right-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-left-container"></div>
    <div class="card-middle-container"></div>
    <div class="card-right-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-left-container"></div>
    <div class="card-middle-container"></div>
    <div class="card-right-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-left-container"></div>
    <div class="card-middle-container"></div>
    <div class="card-right-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-left-container"></div>
    <div class="card-middle-container"></div>
    <div class="card-right-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-left-container"></div>
    <div class="card-middle-container"></div>
    <div class="card-right-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, it was quite simple. Just play with the margin and set the overflow to scroll.

```js
let flag = true;

const setHeight = () => {
  if (flag) {
    document.getElementById('container').style.setProperty('height', '100%');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('container').style.removeProperty('height');
  }
  flag = !flag;
};

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', setHeight);
setHeight();
```

```css
.panel-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 510px;
  padding: 8px 12px 0 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.card {
  height: 86px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  width: 14px;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 4px solid green;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">With/Without overflow</button>
<div id="container" class="panel-container scrollbar">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-left-container"></div>
    <div class="card-middle-container"></div>
    <div class="card-right-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-left-container"></div>
    <div class="card-middle-container"></div>
    <div class="card-right-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-left-container"></div>
    <div class="card-middle-container"></div>
    <div class="card-right-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-left-container"></div>
    <div class="card-middle-container"></div>
    <div class="card-right-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-left-container"></div>
    <div class="card-middle-container"></div>
    <div class="card-right-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-left-container"></div>
    <div class="card-middle-container"></div>
    <div class="card-right-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-left-container"></div>
    <div class="card-middle-container"></div>
    <div class="card-right-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```