# Scrollbar does not have the same behavior in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css

I was trying to avoid vertical scrollbar shift in container ([related to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71266593/avoid-vertical-scrollbar-shift-in-container)) and I succeeded to make it with the margin and the overflow set to scroll. However, on Firefox (see screenshot) the scrollbar is still displayed whereas in chrome/safari/opera (see screenshot) the scrollbar is hidden when it is not needed. I would like Firefox to behave like the others. Is it possible?

I found the property `scrollbar-gutter` but it is not compatible with safari.

**Firefox**

[image]

**Chrome**

[image]

```js
let flag = true;

const setHeight = () => {
  if (flag) {
    document.getElementById('container').style.setProperty('height', '100%');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('container').style.removeProperty('height');
  }
  flag = !flag;
};

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', setHeight);
setHeight();
```

```css
.panel-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 510px;
  padding: 8px 12px 0 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.card {
  height: 86px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  width: 14px;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 4px solid green;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">With/Without overflow</button>
<div id="container" class="panel-container scrollbar">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-left-container"></div>
    <div class="card-middle-container"></div>
    <div class="card-right-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-left-container"></div>
    <div class="card-middle-container"></div>
    <div class="card-right-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-left-container"></div>
    <div class="card-middle-container"></div>
    <div class="card-right-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-left-container"></div>
    <div class="card-middle-container"></div>
    <div class="card-right-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-left-container"></div>
    <div class="card-middle-container"></div>
    <div class="card-right-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-left-container"></div>
    <div class="card-middle-container"></div>
    <div class="card-right-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-left-container"></div>
    <div class="card-middle-container"></div>
    <div class="card-right-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found this experimental feature which does seem to work on FF but gives mixed results on Chrome: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars and here's my attempt at it just using their default code: https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/otywdmzL/15/ Maybe you could try styling it to your liking and see if it gets your desired result? You might be able to use the feature and then target FF specifically for that class. It also looks like it still depends on your `scrollbar` class settings as well as the `scroller` class on Chrome which is kind of strange but it is experimental.